# Matching keywords with large column of words in database - MySQL PHP system

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I have a situation where keywords have to be checked and matched with a database containing over 50000 keywords. It is not just an equal match and it has to search related also.

Example Keyword: James 2
should match James Two, James II etc.

Example Keyword: The God should match God (leaving The)
Similarily keywords like The "God", The 'God' etc should flag similiar entries.

The database if all keywords are stored into a MySQL database.

So
1) what is the most efficient & effective way to do above?
2) Is there any good rule engine where users can enter more logic. Example: remove , (commas) from keyword before search etc? Or should all this be coded into php?

I am happy to setup sphinx or other systems if they are recommended to solve this problem. Soundex and Metaphone are not required as the text should be present in the database as it is to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQL full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), which you can customize to a certain extent.

You can also use other search solutions such as [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) that does all the [tokenzing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization), [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) and lists results according to relevance.